# Android: Application lifecycle and activities

Tags: android

Trying to found some information about Android app life cycle. So imagine the situation: I open app and than lock screen, and in a few hours phone kill my app process. What will happen when I will unlock screen ? What I will see at the screen ? Android home screen ?  or App will restar automatically for me ? Will stack of activities will restore too ? I'll be glad for any help. Thanks...

Comment: i heard the "lifecircle" word for the first time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) is what your looking for.

There is no such thing as Application lifecycle or lifecircle. Every Activity has it's own lifecycle. If the system needs more ram it will be killed if in `onPause()` or `onStop()` state. If all your Activities are killed, the app is no longer visible. If you want data to persist you have to Override `onPause()` and `onResume()` and save/restore your data there.

Your Application will never restore on its own, if there is an activity killed. You have to keep track of your activities manually if you want to "resume" after kill of your activities.

To make it even more precise: One Activity can be killed and the others can remain paused. If you then return to your app you get the last activity in your activity stack which wasn't killed.

Comment: I'm looking for application life circle, not Activity

Comment: yes, but the answer lies within the activity lifecycle. Any activity can be killed if it is in onPause or onStop state.

Comment: Activity can be killed, but not Application

Comment: that's why i refered to activity lifecycle.

Comment: you're welcome! sorry for confusing by not making it clear at first glance.

Comment: I read about Activity lifecycle. So if to talk about the Update2, than it's wrote that if user navigate back to activity that have been killed, than android will recreate that activity for me. That's meen onCreate method will be called.

Answer (score 7):

There is a Life-cycle for the android application BUT the applications have limited control over their own life-cycle, instead the components must listen for changes in the application state and react accordingly, the changes are as the following

1. onCreate
2. onLowMemory
3. onTrimMemory
4. onConfigurationChanged

and these method are accessed by extending the application class and override them to react accordingly.

regards,

Answer (score 0):

If your app was killed by the system then I don't think it will show up when you unlock the screen. If below your app the main screen was there then I assume it will show up since your app has been killed by the system.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you can subclass application class:

> Base class for those who need to maintain global application state.
>   You can provide your own implementation by specifying its name in your
>   AndroidManifest.xml's  tag, which will cause that class
>   to be instantiated for you when the process for your
>   application/package is created.

and then use app callback methods.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html